# Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort' in static HTML page

Tags: html, chromium

I'm unable to understand the meaning of this error which I found in my console in the Edge browser:

```
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.
```

Your guidance is much appreciated.

I can't see any errors in my HTML file, and I don't use Google analytics.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: // This will add JS 
function asya_theme_scripts_function() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'js-file', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js');
  }
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','asya_theme_scripts_function');

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with FLOC. Or Federated Learning of Cohorts. It's an old experiment that Google ran to try to do away with 3rd party cookies. Some code in your website is blocking Floc from running. Unblocking is fairly straight forward to get rid of the warning. But you have to make the decision if you want to unblock floc or leave as is. You will only see this issue in Chrome base browsers. We need to know what type of website you are running? Drupal? Wordpress? Versions?

Comment: I'm running the latest version of WordPress.

Comment: Same here with `mkdocs` + `mkdocs-material` theme on Brave `Version 1.48.171 Chromium: 110.0.5481.177 (Official Build) (arm64)`.

Comment: `Unblocking is fairly straight forward to get rid of the warning` Can you explain a bit more ? It's not straightforward for everyone...

Comment: Also, how should we make the decision to unblock?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same warning but for `browser-topics` by enabling this chrome flag:

```
chrome://flags/#privacy-sandbox-ads-apis
```