# React app gh-pages displaying blank, not sure what to do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, jsx, github-pages

I deployed my react app on gh-pages. I thought I followed all the instructions, but when I open the link it's blank. Any guidance would be great.

Here is the deployed link:
[Website](https://eschiavoni2.github.io/erika.zibelnik/)

Here is the repo:
[Github](https://github.com/eschiavoni2/erika.zibelnik)

I'm not sure what screen grabs would be useful, I'm not seeing anything in the console or anything odd in network.
[image]
[image]

It runs locally without any errors either. If I'm lacking information please let me know what would be helpful. I followed the steps I found for react gh-pages and googled what I could but I'm at a loss.

```
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

https://{username}.github.io/{repo-name}

```
+   "predeploy": "npm run build",
+   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

```
npm run deploy
```

One thing I saw said to use Hashrouter, so I tried that. I tried from a new repo thinking maybe I'd done something incorrectly the first go around so I went step by step again. Help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this in App.js:

```
<Route path="/erika.zibelnik" element={<Home/>}>
```

Also, not sure if this error in the Console is related:

[Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort' in static HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269923/origin-trial-controlled-feature-not-enabled-interest-cohort-in-static-html-pa)

Comment: When I changed the path it now gives me a 404. Before the page was coming up but wasn't displaying anything.

Comment: Now I'm seeing `GET https://eschiavoni2.github.io/static/js/main.a7a21325.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`, so `<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.a7a21325.js"></script>` should be `... src="/erika.zibelnik/static/js/main...`, same with the CSS.  (In general, try getting more clues about errors from the Console tab and the Network tab)

Comment: What would cause that? I'm not sure why it would do that.

Comment: I guess I'm at a loss, because you said there are errors in console, but I'm not getting any errors in console. They appear the same as my first screen grab of the console.

Comment: Looks like you got it working now?

Comment: Yeah, I removed my node_modules, reinstalled, ran through all the steps again and then it worked with your suggestions. Thank you for the help. I think I accepted the answer? Appreciate it!